# Exceute code only certain window size without relaoding the page jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to run this code when window size hit certain width.
This code is working on page load, i want it to run when user resize the browser window.

```
if ($(window).width() > 1023) {
        $('.has-children').children('a').on('click', function(event){
            if( !checkWindowWidth() ) event.preventDefault();
            var selected = $(this);
            if( selected.next('ul').hasClass('is-hidden') ) {
                selected.addClass('selected').next('ul').removeClass('is-hidden').end().parent('.has-children').parent('ul').addClass('moves-out');
                selected.parent('.has-children').siblings('.has-children').children('ul').addClass('is-hidden').end().children('a').removeClass('selected');
                $('.insided-overlay').addClass('is-visible');
            } else {
                selected.removeClass('selected').next('ul').addClass('is-hidden').end().parent('.has-children').parent('ul').removeClass('moves-out');
                $('.insided-overlay').removeClass('is-visible');

            }
        });
    }
```

Can anyone please help me with this how can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: This code would only check `$(window).width()` on page load. Have you tried putting this check within the `.on('click')` handler?

Comment: Non i did not try like that, can you please show me a example. how can i do that? Thanks

Comment: `$(selector).on('click', function() { if ($(window.width) > 1023) { bigger window stuff } else { smaller window stuff } });`

Answer (score 0):

try to write this script as below:

```
$('.has-children').children('a').on('click', function(event){
    if($(window).width() > 1023) {
        if( !checkWindowWidth() ) event.preventDefault();
        var selected = $(this);
        if( selected.next('ul').hasClass('is-hidden') ) {
            selected.addClass('selected').next('ul').removeClass('is-hidden').end().parent('.has-children').parent('ul').addClass('moves-out');
            selected.parent('.has-children').siblings('.has-children').children('ul').addClass('is-hidden').end().children('a').removeClass('selected');
            $('.insided-overlay').addClass('is-visible');
        } else {
            selected.removeClass('selected').next('ul').addClass('is-hidden').end().parent('.has-children').parent('ul').removeClass('moves-out');
            $('.insided-overlay').removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this will works fine for you.

Thank you...

Comment: This would rebind the `.on('click')` handler every time the user resizes the window. Not exactly efficient.

Comment: I have just edit my answer please check it once by putting this to your code. you just have to check you window width on clicking of the "$('.has-children').children('a')". i hope this will works for you.

Comment: you just have to check window width while click on button not need to change anything on window resize.

Comment: onclick is working fine, but the issue is when click windows less than 1023 width it shows dropdown with different styling, if from here resize the window to less 767 it also takes the styling of 1023. so the menu look messed up. Without reload the page styling of less than 767 does not show up.